# Function pointer in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, function-pointers

Consider the following function

```
Function IfFunctionExistsExecute
{
    param ([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$func)
    begin 
    {
        # ...
    }
    process
    {
        if(Get-Command $func -ea SilentlyContinue)
        {
            & $func # the amperersand invokes the function instead of just printing the variable
        }
        else
        {
            # ignore
        }       
    }
    end
    {
        # ...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Function Foo { "In Foo" }
IfFunctionExistsExecute Foo
```

This works.

However this doesn't work:

```
Function Foo($someParam) 
{ 
     "In Foo"
     $someParam
}

IfFunctionExistsExecute Foo "beer"
```

However this gives me the ugly error:

```
IfFunctionExistsExecute : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'beer'.
At C:\PSTests\Test.ps1:11 char:24
+ IfFunctionExistsExecute <<<<  Foo "beer"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [IfFunctionExistsExecute], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,IfFunctionExistsExecute
```

How can I do this in PS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an optional parameter on the function your calling, and on your `IfFunctionExistsExecute` function; something like this:

```
Function IfFunctionExistsExecute
{
    param ([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$func, [string]$myArgs)
        if(Get-Command $func -ea SilentlyContinue)
        {
            & $func $myArgs  # the amperersand invokes the function instead of just printing the variable
        }
        else
        {
            # ignore
        }       
}

Function Foo
{ 
    param ([parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$someParam)
    "In Foo" 
    $someParam
}

IfFunctionExistsExecute Foo
IfFunctionExistsExecute Foo "beer"
```

For me this gives:

```
C:\test>powershell .\test.ps1
In Foo

In Foo
beer

C:\test>
```

Comment: Seems that the issue was that my module wasn't being reloaded when I edited it :(

Comment: don't use $args as your own parameter name , as that is a built in automatic parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should pass arguments to the called function as well:

```
$arguments = $args[1..($args.Length-1)]
& $func @arguments
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't do the trick, same error... I even tried to add the $args to the param list of the IfFunctionExistsExecute method.

Comment: Ok, it works half, the @ thingy (whatever that does) passes it in as comma seperated, like this: Foo b,e,e,r. Which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my solution. Function named by powershell's style: *Verb-Noun*. It supports named parameters and remaining arguments.

```
function Invoke-FunctionIfExist {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # Function name
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)]
        [string]
        $Name,
        # Hashtable with named arguments
        [Parameter()]
        [hashtable]
        $Parameters = @{},
        # Rest of arguments
        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
        [object[]]
        $Arguments = @()
    )

    process {
        if (Get-Command $Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
            & $Name @NamedArguments @Arguments
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
PS> Invoke-FunctionIfExist Foo
In Foo
PS> Invoke-FunctionIfExist Foo beer
In Foo
beer
PS> Invoke-FunctionIfExist Foo -Parameters @{someParam='beer'}
In Foo
beer
```